# How do I add nice values to a plank docker app so they execute on launch without having to enter the command in terminal every time

Tags: plank

How do I add nice values to an app in the docker so it can launch every time with having to run terminal  i.e. nice firefox -20  I am looking specifically at elementary os docker and how to add the execution command within the docker.

Comment: Read this article: https://www.tecmint.com/set-linux-process-priority-using-nice-and-renice-commands/ Sorry I do not see sense in replicating the same content and wasting time. Nice, renice is a part of RHCSA.

Comment: I was looking specifically at elementary OS docker and how to add a nice command within the docker

Comment: It is not possible. I provided the link, because there is an explanation how to do it. Elementary OS is not special in this case. Nice, renice works in every Linux distribution.